# Could not find an appropriate PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, windows-10, phantomjs

При попытки поставить Фантом для использование в Ruby and Jasmine, выдает такую ошибку все компоненты обновлены до последних версий

> Phantomjs::UnknownPlatform: Could not find an appropriate PhantomJS library for your platform (x64-mingw32 :( Please install manually.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто как решал данную проблему?

Comment: А почему вы не используете версию для Windows?
Описанная вами проблема известная и у нее нет решения (https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem/issues/18).

Comment: так я и скачивал версию для виндовс, поставил еще руби х32 теперь такая трабла

Phantomjs does not appear to be installed in C:/Users/.../.phantomjs/2.1.1/win32/bin/phantomjs.exe, installing!
rake aborted!


Failed to load phantomjs! :(
You need to have cURL or wget installed on your system.

Comment: Обновите вопрос на основе комментария. Одно дело установка PhantomJS, другое дело установка PhantomJS для использования в Ruby.

Comment: jasmine server started
Can't open ''C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jasmine-2.4.0/lib/jasmine/runners/phantom_jasmine_run.js''

0 specs, 0 failures

Пока добился такого. И да для руби и жасмина ставлю

Comment: Повторяю. Обновляйте вопрос, а не пишите в комментариях свои уточнения.